# code sign identity: Automatic

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I used to have Automatic code sign identity: iPhone Developer to test on real device (it matched to my "development" certificate).

Soon in my target's settings, I've faced with no ability to choose "iPhone Developer" and I don't see any of my developer certificates but just "distribution" profile:

[image]

On the other hand on the same Project, on my project's settings (not target) I can see it:

(but it still doesn't match to my certificates)

[image]

I've tried to restart `XCode`, clean project etc, nothing help...
So what's wrong with my target?

Comment: are you using same bundle identifier for both targets ?

Comment: sure, it matches my app's identifier under developer's account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, the problem was that wrong "distribution profile" was set under "Provisioning profile" option.

That's why I wasn't able to set code sign identity to "iPhone developer" etc...